# How to place error message appropriately in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have check boxes for working days if user does't select any one of the checkbox we need to show error message but after showing error message alignment is not correct as shon in the below picture.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaGEi.png]

Comment: What is the HTML code you have along with css?? Can you post it?

Answer (score 0):

You can move your check boxes validation to @Html.ValidationSummary() 
(i.e. don't create @Html.ValidationMessageFor() for every checkbox, but display it in separate html div)